# git - error while trying to commit a C++ project

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket, smartgit

I have made a repository on bitbucket.org for a C++ project.

I downloaded git on my computer installed it and also installed as client, SmartGIT.

I have generated a set of keys by using puttygen. After the generating step, I have added the public key data in bitbucket in the SSH keys section of my project and while cloning the repository on my computer by using SmartGIT, I have added the OpenSSH key saved from puttygen.

I have added my project in the repository folder from my computer and now, when I try to commit my changes, I receive the following error:

```
The remote end hung up unexpectedly.
conq: repository access denied. access via a deployment key is read-only.
```

What should I do in order to be able to commit changes on the repository? I am a beginner at using GIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've most likely added your SSH key to the `Deployment Keys` section of our project. Keys added there will only give read only access.

What you want to do is to remove the key from there and instead add it under `Manage Account -> SSH keys`. Keys added there will give full read/write access to repositories your user has access to.

I'm not sure what happens if you added a key in both places, but just in case you have, remove the key from deployment keys.